# unexpected return value of Boolean() function

Tags: javascript

In order to determine if an object is an array or an object list, I came up with this approach:

```
var foo = {}
Boolean(foo["length"]+1) // returns false because foo is an object


var foo = []
Boolean(foo["length"]+1) // returns true because foo is an array
```

However, after looking at this, I realized it shouldn't work.
`[]["length"]+1` is obviously true because it is equal to 1. `{}["length"]+1` is equal to `"length1"` which also is true because it is not undefined.

So why is it that `Boolean({}["length"]+1)` returns false yet `Boolean("length1")` returns true?

Comment: foo being `{}` and foo['length'] results in undefined, and undefined + 1 is NaN.  NaN is falsy

Comment: While this is an interesting example of JS type conversions, wouldn't you be better off simply using `Array.isArray()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: @wilsonwilson As a developer you really should be mindful of the effort you put into reinventing the wheel. Frequently if you need something somebody else has already put a lot more thought into it than you. And even if they havent reviewing their process will give you a better idea regarding your own solution. In this case there is a [native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) implementation you can rely on instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *So why is it that `Boolean({}["length"]+1)` returns false...*

Because objects don't have a `length` property, so `{}["length"]` is going to return `undefined` and trying to do `+1` on `undefined` is `NaN`, which is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value.

> *...yet `Boolean("length1")` returns true?*

Because the string `length1` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value.

A better test would be to see if the item in question has a property/method that only one of them has. This is called ["feature detection"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) and is used widely throughout JavaScript

```js
let obj1 = {};
let obj2 = [];

console.log(obj1.length);         // undefined: objects don't have length
console.log(obj1.hasOwnProperty); // native function (ie. truthy) 
console.log(obj2.length);         // 0: Arrays have length and this one's is 0
console.log(obj2.map);            // the native function (ie. truthy)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean({}["length"]+1)` returns `false` because there is no `length` property on object i.e `{}` so it returns `undefined` and `undefined + 1` returns `NaN` 
which is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value

```
Boolean({}["length"]+1)
Boolean(undefined+1)
Boolean(NaN)
false
```

`Boolean("length1")` returns true because `"length1"` is string and trucy value. Note all the strings are trucy except empty string `""`

The following values will always return `false` when will coerced to `Boolean` and all other will return `true`

```js
console.log(Boolean(0));
console.log(Boolean(''));
console.log(Boolean(null));
console.log(Boolean(undefined));
console.log(Boolean(false));
console.log(Boolean(NaN));
```